Error al exportar un xlsx desde R
Cuando intento exportar a excel un dataframe de R me da este error:
Error in .jcall(row[[ir]], "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell;", "createCell",  : 
  Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>

Para exportar uso la función write.xlsx:
write.xlsx(dataframe, file = "nombrearchivo.xlsx")


Fijate esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755678/write-xlsx-error-in-error-in-jnew-and-j-check-in-r

Me pasó lo mismo, al parecer ese error aparece cuando el df que quieres exportar es demasiado grande, lo solucioné exportando en .csv en lugar de .xlsx:
write.csv(df, file= "Dirección/"nombre_del_archivo.csv", row.names=FALSE)
